Where does Yubaba go when she goes out?
There are scenes where Yubaba is shown leaving the hotel and she turns into a bird. Is there any indication of where she goes?

What you see is what you get, so, again, unless someone from Ghibli has an answer, then your guess is as good as anyone else’s.
